# Postfix sender blacklist

Tags: postfix, blacklist

I'm running my own mail server (Ubuntu, Postfix, MySQL, Dovecot, Amavis, SpamAssassin, ...) since years for my family's mailboxes (5 mailboxes in total). 
I always try to improve my antispam filters. Today I got tired with this and decided to become more aggressive and create a blacklist. 
Using the Postfix sender_access setting, I'm storing blacklisted email addresses or hostnames into my MySQL database. And this is working just fine. 
I also wrote a sieve script to move marketing emails into another mailbox in order to distinct them from regular emails. This is working most of the times (except when the List-Unsubscribe header is missing).

But I have a tiny problem. Sometimes, the "from" address that postfix uses for sender_access does not match the "from" header of the email - which I know is perfectly normal. But this is annoying because when blacklisting a new address, I must search into the log files the original "from" instead of blacklisting the visible "from" header of the email.

Plus, I must sometimes blacklist entire emailing platforms domains. For example, a SPAM sent from "newsletter@imaspammer.com" is sent through the emailing platform "serv1.mailing.newsletters.com". So I must blacklist "mailing.newsletters.com" instead of "imaspammer.com" and take the risk to blacklist HAM emails or newsletters.

Is there a way to prevent this? I'm pretty sure that sender_access requires the original "from" and that can't be changed. So what are my options? I'm thinking about writing my own Perl pipe script.

Thanks a lot,

Axel

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the *envelope sender* addresses in your `sender_access`. The `From:` header can be easily spoofed to be anything, and an MTA should deliver the message as it is, merely adding its own lines at the beginning.

The `From:` header should ([RFC 2822, 3.6.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.6.2)) specify the author(s) of the message, the one responsible for the writing of the message. It's perfectly normal that another address sends mail on behalf ot the author, mailing lists being one example, not being able to use the address as  envelope sender due to SPF.

> when blacklisting a new address, I must search into the log files the original "from"

That's only partly true. You can find the envelope sender from the email headers too. It's added by the MTA that delivers the message in the mailbox i.e. your Postfix, and it's called `Return-Path:`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are right, I noticed that the Return-Path matches the original "From". Still ! It means I must blacklist entire marketing plateforms sometimes. Some of their clients may send legitimate emails...

Comment: Just proving my previous message, I just received a dating website SPAM sent from "@rdv-libertins.fr" but with Return-path from "1121-41d6-8b0c-4b733c6f9852-000000@amazonses.com". I will not block *amazonses.com" so I will try to block the entire address. I hope this is reliable and that this unreadable code is not changing each time.

Comment: aaaaand what I feared happened! The Return Path does change between two emails of this sender. So I'm unable to block this sender unless I block *amazonses.com. Any idea ?

Comment: Is Spamassassin out of question? Or does it not recognize these as spam? Could it be configured or educated (bayesian) to do so?

Comment: You are right, Spamassassin does work fine ... when you train it. My father kept 5000+ SPAM emails and newsletters into his INBOX, half of them as UNREAD. So I told him again. But some spammers really deserve blacklisting. Let's work with spamassassin for now. Thanks